# Simulating shuffle in js

Tags: javascript

All,

I have three cards which can be shuffled by the user, upon hover, the target card pops to the top, the last card on top should sit in the second position. While with the code below, I can have this effect in one direction (left to right), I am struggling to come up with logic & code for getting the effect to work in both directions without having to write multiple scenarios in js (which doesnt sound like very good logic).

Hopefully the [demo](http://jsbin.com/oqocoy/3/edit) will do a better explanation.

Code:

```
$(".cBBTemplates").on (
{
    hover: function (e)
    {
        var aBBTemplates = document.getElementsByClassName ("cBBTemplates");
        var i = 2;
        while (i < aBBTemplates.length && i >= 0)
        {
            var eCurVar = aBBTemplates[i];
            if (eCurVar === e.target)
            {
                eCurVar.style.zIndex = 3;
            }   else if (eCurVar.style.zIndex === 3)    {
                console.log (eCurVar);
                eCurVar.style.zIndex = 3-1;
            }   else
            {
                eCurVar.style.zIndex = i;
            }
            i--;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Supposing zindices of 1, 2 and 3. Your logic could keep in one variable a pointer to the card in the front. Upon hover, you change the target zindex to 3 and remove 1 from the zindex of the others until both values (of the two cards) are less than 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    var current = 2;
   $(".cBBTemplates").on (
{
    hover: function ()
    {
      var target = this,
      newCurrent, templates = $(".cBBTemplates");

      templates.each(
        function(idx){
           if(this === target){
             newCurrent = idx;
           }
       });

  if(newCurrent === current){return;}


      templates.each(function(index){
          var zIndex = 0;
        if(this === target) {
          zIndex = 2;
        }
        else if (index == current) {
          zIndex = 1; 
        }

        $(this).css('zIndex', zIndex);

      });

      current = newCurrent;
    }
});
```

});

Comment: thanks, however, there is a flaw in your code, when you hover from right to left, at the left-most card, upon mouse out, the 3rd card comes on top of the second. http://jsbin.com/oqocoy/5/edit

Comment: Not sure I clearly understand you. You asked for 'upon hover, the target card pops to the top, the last card on top should sit in the second position' which is what this code is actually doing.

Comment: its not. Have a go at the demo and hover from right most card to the left, all appears fine until you move your cursor away from the last most card. Give it a go.

Comment: Removed double triggering on the same card.